# Security riddle: confirming email and resetting passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, devise, passwords, devise-confirmable

I'm using Devise on my Rails 3.0 app, and we currently have confirmable and recoverable turned on. These modules require users to confirm their email account (confirmable) and allow users to reset their password by having an email sent to their email account (recoverable).

Unfortunately we've had difficulty "devising" (pun intended) a reasonable security policy that permits users to use the site without confirming their account. We enforce the following requirements for security:

1. Confirming your account requires being signed in or signing in. Were this not the case and user A accidentally entered the wrong email address of malicious user B, B would receive the confirm email link, get automatically signed in, and from there could reset the password via "email reset password link." Requiring B to sign in with A's credentials eliminates this possibility.
2. Resetting your password via email requires having a confirmed email. This is because if user A accidentally enters the wrong email address, one belonging to malicious user B, then B will receive the confirm email link and know that A has signed up for an account. So B can visit the site and use the reset password functionality to change the password on the account, and subsequently can confirm his account. Requiring a confirmed email address eliminates this possibility.

So all is well. Except when user A creates an account, doesn't confirm his account yet, and then returns to the site and forgets his password. Here A is caught in a circular dependency loop, where resetting his password requires confirming his account, but confirming his account requires signing in with a password that he has forgotten.

Two possible solutions:

1. Requiring users to confirm their account immediately after signing in. This creates more sign-up friction, but eliminates the circular dependency.
2. Permitting users to reset their password without a confirmed account, but not allowing users to enter any sensitive information or perform critical actions before confirming their account. This way an account hijack by malicious user B is still possible, but he will gain control of an account without any valuable information or power.

Are there better solutions out there? How do companies deal with this issue? I've used several sites that do not require immediate email confirmation, so it'd be nice if we could do this in a way that doesn't require implementing something as complicated as #2.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey. Any follow-up on this? I was looking through my past answers and saw that this still didn't have an accepted answer. Did you end up making a decision, or is it still being designed?

Answer (score 0):

Create a sort of *role* where a user is authenticated, but not confirmed. It is not unreasonable to require a user to confirm their account before making any account changes (such as resetting their password or email address).

I think the trick here is really just that you can let a user confirm account without being logged in. If User A put in the wrong email address, then what can you expect to do? Do your best to help them put in the right email address at the beginning. This is a rather unforgivable sin for the user - they should know how to put in their email address. If they can't get the email, and used the wrong account, the last resort is for you to do some tech support and/or give them some security questions to help them recover their account.

After clicking the "confirm" link in their email, they should be asked to log in. Simple as that. "Thanks for confirming your account, please log in". Don't automatically log them in, as this could be a security issue, especially if they have a "profile" with sensitive information.

In your scenario where a non-confirmed user forgets their password. Tell them they have to confirm their account first, offer to resend the email. After that, give them the option to reset their password via email. It is clunky, but the user will probably be understanding if you explain *why* they have to go through this. They are the ones forgetting all their information, so they shouldn't be too harsh on you.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I might be misunderstanding, but it seems that your proposal still permits malicious users to hijack an account: user A enters the wrong email address and continues using the site, entering some personal info. Later malicious user B whose email A accidentally entered receives a "confirm your account" email, which he clicks. Under your proposal, the system confirms the account but does not sign in B. Then user B uses the "Forgot password?" functionality, which sends a reset password link to his email address. He resets the password and enters A's account!

Comment: @oregontrail256 I get what you are saying, and if this is truly a concern for your user base, you should account for this. Either by making them confirm up front, or answer security questions before resetting their password. My argument was that it is not unreasonable to expect the user to enter their actual email address. But security questions and confirming before activating the account are the way to protect against this that I have seen.